# Using Jquery to get a specific element out of many repeated classes on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this bit of code that repeates.

```
<div class='commentfloatleft'>
                <button type='button' class='button2' onclick='upvote($id8)'>
                    <img src='images/likebutton.png'    class='upvoteimage' width='12' height='12' alt='PearlSquirrel'/>
                </button>
                <button type='button' class='button2' onclick='downvote($id8)'>
                    <img src='images/unlikebutton.png' width='12' height='12' alt='PearlSquirrel'/>
                </button>
            </div>
```

When I click on the onclick code for upvote is this:

```
function upvote(box){
$(this).siblings('.upvoteimage').load('upvote.php?box=' + box);
}
```

I have tried everything to get this to work.  The get function is working, but I can not see any changes in ".upvoteimage".  Does anyone know how to fix this problem.  Help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: to get buttons fired they need to be surrounded by `<form></form>`

Comment: Untrue, that's just to get the form fired.

Comment: Which he already has(inline, not best practice but it works)

Comment: What kind of variable is `$id8` being used in `upvote($id8)`?

Comment: it is the specific id of the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way: set a class "upvote" to your "button" element:

```
<div class='commentfloatleft'>
                <button type='button' class='button2 upvote' id='$id8'>
                    <img src='images/likebutton.png'    class='upvoteimage' width='12' height='12' alt='PearlSquirrel'/>
                </button>
                <button type='button' class='button2' onclick='downvote()'>
                    <img src='images/unlikebutton.png' width='12' height='12' alt='PearlSquirrel'/>
                </button>
            </div>​
```

And use this JS code:

```
$(".upvote").on("click",function(){
    var box=$(this).attr("id");
    $(this).find('.upvoteimage').attr("src",'upvote.php?box=' + box);
    return false;
}​);​
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code says siblings but .upvoteimage is not a sibling but a child. Try using find/children instead.

And $(this) probably doesn't exist in the function. Maybe you should move the onclick event to the script block instead. jQuery has some great features not to work with inline code.

Comment: Ashirvad Singh answered with the complete package(just not yet explaining it all)

Answer (score 2):

try this

**HTML**

```
  <div class='commentfloatleft'>
                    <button type='button' class='button2' onclick='upvote(this,\x27$id8\x27)'>
                        <img src='images/likebutton.png'    class='upvoteimage' width='12' height='12' alt='PearlSquirrel'/>
                    </button>
                    <button type='button' class='button2' onclick='downvote($id8)'>
                        <img src='images/unlikebutton.png' width='12' height='12' alt='PearlSquirrel'/>
                    </button>
                </div>
```

YOur jQuery Code:

```
function upvote(obj,box){
$(obj).children('.upvoteimage').load('upvote.php?box=' + box);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the siblings of the button, and filtering for those of class upvoteimage.

What you want to be doing is reference the siblings, then select their children of class upvoteimage:

```
$(this).siblings('.button2').children('.upvoteimage').load('upvote.php?box=' + box);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a child not a sibling thats y it is not happening

you can try

```
$(this).siblings('.button2' > '.upvoteimage')
```

I think some what like this will work

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind events instead of doing it inline.

In your `upvote` function `this` is the window object not the button clicked.

The img with the upvote class is a child of the button not a sibling.

You cant load anything into an img tag, its an empty tag